# Is the relative order of elements in column matrices $Mf(x)$ and $Mx$ the same if $f$ is strictly increasing?

Tags: matrices, functions

Suppose we have an $n$ by $1$ matrix A. We define $\arg\max A$ as the $k$ such that the largest element of A is $A_{k, 1}$.

Consider a $m$ by $n$ matrix $M$ with nonnegative entries and an $n$ by $p$ matrix $p$. Let $x = \arg\max Mp$.

Now take a strictly increasing function $f$, and let $x' = \arg\max M f(p)$, where $f$ is applied elementwise.

Is $x = x'$? Every example I try works, but I'm not sure how to prove it. I feel like a proof needs to leverage the relationship between increasing functions and rank-preservation, but I can't seem to put my finger on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, because the matrix mixes up the elements.

For example, let $$M:=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&3\end{pmatrix},\qquad p=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix},\qquad f(x):=2^x,$$ then $$Mp=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix},\qquad Mf(p)=\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on why/how it "mixes up the elements"? If you interpret $M$ as an array of $m$ options and $p$ as a preference vector, it intuitively seems like the only thing that should matter is the relative order of the elements in the preference vector.

Comment: @actinidia Well, look at the example. Given an "option" $(a,b)$ with $a<b$, applied to a preference $(x,y)$, we get $ax+by$. If $(x,y)$ increases then the increase in $y$ matters more than the increase in $x$. So it can happen, as in the example, that although $x>y$, the increase in $y$ more than offsets the increase in $x$.